# Maruti, is this the name of Lord Hanuman or his mother Or both?

Tags: hindu

I have heard so many times that **Maruti** is the other name of Lord Hanuman. Also heard that Maruti Nandan (The son of Maruti)

> *Hey dukh bhanjan Maruti nandan Sunlo meri pukar..*

Which one is correct? Or Lord Hanuman is named as though his mother is Maruti?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should explain ([source](http://www.speakingtree.in/blog/why-hanuman-is-called-maruti)):

> Maruti is a highly popular name used to address Hanuman. The literal
>   meaning of the word 'Maruti' is the one who is born from 'Marut',
>   meaning air. The other names that suggest Hanuman is the son of Air
>   god include Maruti Nandan (Air god's son), Marutadmaja (the one born
>   from Air), Vayu Putra (Air god's son), and others. There is an
>   interesting story how Vayu or the Air god became Hanuman's father.

Essentially, Marut refers to air, and Maruti can refer to Vayu (god of air) or Hanuman (born from/of air or Vayu). In the name of Maruti-Nandan, Maruti refers to Vayu.

Answer (score 3):

Maruti is the name of Hanuman and not of his mother.

In the line

> Hey dukh bhanjan Maruti nandan Sunlo meri pukar..

Maruti nandan means child Maruti (like you would call someone child 'Name', young 'Name', adult 'Name' or old 'Name' replacing Name with anyone's name in this case Maruti) and not child of Maruti.

Answer (score 0):

Marut is the Wind God, and Hanuman is his son.  Because of this, he becomes Maruti Nandan.  (Marut with a short vowel at the beginning, gets elongated when the case changes in Sanskrit).